# Is a tax-deductible IRA contribution applied before the AGI income limit is checked?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, ira, limits

If your AGI is above the limits defined by the IRS, you cannot deduct *Traditional IRA contributions*.

What if deduction of the Traditional IRA contributions would reduce the AGI just under the limit?

Basically: checking AGI limit comes first, or Deduction comes first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your eligibility is determined by calculating your modified adjusted gross income (MAGI) *without* the IRA deduction. The details of the MAGI calculation are available from the IRS [here](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590a/ch01.html#en_US_2016_publink100025076).